# mysql query return wrong data type of a table column

Tags: php, mysql, casting, var-dump

I'm querying , in a mysql db, a table of two columns : first one is of type int and the second one of type VARCHAR type, my query looks like this:

```
    try {
        $PDOStatment = $db->query(
    "SELECT country_id, name   FROM country ORDER BY  country_id ;");

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
            exit;
        }

    $array = $PDOStatment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ; 

    var_dump($array);
    exit;
```

when checking the result of the query with var_dump($array) I'm getting an array with  all items of type string! ( I narrowed the error I was getting in my remaining code to this bug), though country_id column is showing correctly as integer type using phpMyAdmin structure tab! I need this column to be retrieved as it is an integer type for use in the remaining code of the  web application.

Comment: PHP will automatically convert strings to numbers when they're used in arithmetic, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Like Barmar has said, strings will automatically be converted to numbers in arithmetic so no need to worry. However, you can still use **intval()** as a precaution for correct usage in your remaining code.

So as a precaution, you can add the following code snippet into your code.

```
$result = $PDOStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);    
foreach($result as $country_id) {
  $country_id = intval($country_id);
}
```

This will make sure that $country_id are all integers!

Comment: Thank you. what I'm using the returned array for is to populate a form's select drop down menu.I have three tables the main table have two foreign key columns referencing the other two tables primary key columns one of which is this country table. I tried to adapt your code to this usage but with no success. I'm still working on the issue! Always failing to get the proper int value of the country_id column into the "<option="value"> so as to properly submit the new record into the child(main) table!

Answer (score 0):

In PDO all records will be returned as strings,it`s not a bug.Just cast it manually to what type you want.